# Minecraft "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I'm trying to play Minecraft on PC, but the system crashes. I have added the report from the computer below.

Can anyone help me solve this, so that I can play?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000595355ec, pid=8088, tid=9052
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4dev64.dll+0x55ec]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000001d60000):  JavaThread "Client thread" [_thread_in_native, id=9052, stack(0x00000000020b0000,0x00000000021b0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0000000063a7d000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000ffffff, RBX=0x000000000038f270, RCX=0x00000000000001e0, RDX=0x000000000000ff00
RSP=0x00000000021ae9f0, RBP=0x00000000000001e0, RSI=0x0000000000000076, RDI=0x0000000063a7d000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000063a7d000, R10=0x0000000000000d80, R11=0x0000000000ffffff
R12=0x0000000000000020, R13=0x000000000042b440, R14=0x000000005c9fbb80, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x00000000595355ec, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000021ae9f0)
0x00000000021ae9f0:   00000000021aea90 000000000038f270
0x00000000021aea00:   00000000000001e0 0000000000000000
0x00000000021aea10:   00000000021aea50 000000000038f270
0x00000000021aea20:   0000000000000000 00000000000001e0
0x00000000021aea30:   0000000000000000 0000000000ffffff
0x00000000021aea40:   000000005c9de150 000000005953ad68
0x00000000021aea50:   0000000000000d80 00000000021aea90
0x00000000021aea60:   000000000042bd50 0000000063810000
0x00000000021aea70:   0000000000ffffff 00000000021aea90
0x00000000021aea80:   0000000059e100b0 0000000000000000
0x00000000021aea90:   0000000000000000 000001e000000356
0x00000000021aeaa0:   00000000021aeb20 0000000059197395
0x00000000021aeab0:   000000005ca2d020 0000000059537de7
0x00000000021aeac0:   0000000000000000 0000000059537de7
0x00000000021aead0:   00000000021aeae0 000000005c9da5d0
0x00000000021aeae0:   0000000000000000 000001e000000356 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000595355ec)
0x00000000595355cc:   44 0b d8 45 0b d8 85 f6 0f 8e 98 00 00 00 66 66
0x00000000595355dc:   90 66 66 90 85 ed 7e 0f 8b cd 41 8b c3 49 8b f9
0x00000000595355ec:   f3 ab 44 8b 54 24 60 41 8b c2 83 ee 01 4c 03 c8
0x00000000595355fc:   85 f6 7f e0 eb 70 8b bc 24 80 00 00 00 48 8b 94 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000ffffff is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000000038f270 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000000001e0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000000ff00 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000000021ae9f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000001d60000
RBP=0x00000000000001e0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000076 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000063a7d000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000063a7d000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000d80 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000ffffff is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000020 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000000042b440 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000005c9fbb80 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00000000020b0000,0x00000000021b0000],  sp=0x00000000021ae9f0,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ig4dev64.dll+0x55ec]
C  [ig4dev64.dll+0xad68]
C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x297395]
C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x29090a]
C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x18a71b]
C  [ig4dev64.dll+0xdcad]
C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x355ab]
C  0x0000000002493874

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglClear(IJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear(I)V+15
j  bmg.f()V+54
j  bmg.b(II)V+181
j  bmg.a(II)V+37
j  bmg.<init>(IIZ)V+62
j  bbo.<init>(Lbao;)V+62
j  bao.ag()V+1236
j  bao.f()V+6
j  net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+1007
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000572aa000 JavaThread "Thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=8020, stack(0x0000000060bf0000,0x0000000060cf0000)]
  0x000000005793f800 JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=7160, stack(0x0000000060a00000,0x0000000060b00000)]
  0x0000000057678800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8924, stack(0x0000000058a10000,0x0000000058b10000)]
  0x00000000575b1000 JavaThread "Timer hack thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1676, stack(0x0000000058420000,0x0000000058520000)]
  0x0000000057719000 JavaThread "Snooper Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7316, stack(0x0000000058210000,0x0000000058310000)]
  0x0000000056718800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7716, stack(0x0000000056e20000,0x0000000056f20000)]
  0x0000000056713800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8752, stack(0x0000000056c40000,0x0000000056d40000)]
  0x0000000055b57800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5796, stack(0x0000000056610000,0x0000000056710000)]
  0x0000000055b63000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6312, stack(0x0000000056460000,0x0000000056560000)]
  0x0000000055b62000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7844, stack(0x00000000562d0000,0x00000000563d0000)]
  0x0000000055b60800 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8880, stack(0x0000000056080000,0x0000000056180000)]
  0x0000000055af8000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6600, stack(0x0000000055ec0000,0x0000000055fc0000)]
  0x0000000055af1000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9064, stack(0x0000000055dc0000,0x0000000055ec0000)]
=>0x0000000001d60000 JavaThread "Client thread" [_thread_in_native, id=9052, stack(0x00000000020b0000,0x00000000021b0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000055ae7000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000055bd0000,0x0000000055cd0000] [id=6772]
  0x0000000056722000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000057070000,0x0000000057170000] [id=8188]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 31614K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,  20% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c155d8b8, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  74% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7001fd8, 0x00000000c7340000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 33552K, used 32445K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000ca0c4000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 21824K, capacity 21991K, committed 22216K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2723K, capacity 2782K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000119d0000,0x0000000011be0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000113d0000

Marking Bits: (CMSBitMap*) 0x0000000001da05b8
 Bits: [0x0000000011fd0000, 0x0000000012dd0000)

Mod Union Table: (CMSBitMap*) 0x0000000001da0678
 Bits: [0x0000000001e40000, 0x0000000001e78000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000300000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=7382Kb max_used=7384Kb free=238377Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002480000, 0x0000000002bc0000, 0x0000000011480000]
 total_blobs=2787 nmethods=2176 adapters=525
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 14.508 Thread 0x0000000056713800 2182       3       bpw::<init> (64 bytes)
Event: 14.508 Thread 0x0000000056713800 nmethod 2182 0x0000000002bb9d10 code [0x0000000002bb9ea0, 0x0000000002bba450]
Event: 14.556 Thread 0x0000000056713800 2186       1       sun.util.calendar.CalendarDate::setNormalized (6 bytes)
Event: 14.556 Thread 0x0000000056713800 nmethod 2186 0x000000000259f010 code [0x000000000259f160, 0x000000000259f270]
Event: 14.594 Thread 0x0000000056713800 2188       3       qh::b (40 bytes)
Event: 14.594 Thread 0x0000000056713800 nmethod 2188 0x00000000025a37d0 code [0x00000000025a3920, 0x00000000025a3a90]
Event: 14.650 Thread 0x0000000056713800 2189       3       java.util.Random::<init> (53 bytes)
Event: 14.651 Thread 0x0000000056713800 nmethod 2189 0x0000000002bb9190 code [0x0000000002bb9340, 0x0000000002bb9a28]
Event: 14.651 Thread 0x0000000056713800 2190       3       java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong::<init> (10 bytes)
Event: 14.651 Thread 0x0000000056713800 nmethod 2190 0x0000000002bb8d10 code [0x0000000002bb8e80, 0x0000000002bb90b0]

GC Heap History (4 events):
Event: 11.807 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 104960K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 6144K, used 0K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8600000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 20330K, capacity 20455K, committed 20864K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2563K, capacity 2590K, committed 2688K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 11.877 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 13055K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  99% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7fffff8, 0x00000000c8000000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 24584K, used 21624K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c9802000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 20330K, capacity 20455K, committed 20864K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2563K, capacity 2590K, committed 2688K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 14.008 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 118015K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  99% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7fffff8, 0x00000000c8000000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 24584K, used 21624K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c9802000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 21687K, capacity 21799K, committed 21960K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2711K, capacity 2782K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 14.149 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 9735K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  74% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7001fd8, 0x00000000c7340000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 33552K, used 32445K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000ca0c4000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 21687K, capacity 21799K, committed 21960K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2711K, capacity 2782K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 13.527 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b17438 method=bqi.a(IIIII)I @ 38
Event: 13.540 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b22964 method=bqi.a(IIIIZ)I @ 285
Event: 13.556 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b20b20 method=bqi.a(IIIII)I @ 16
Event: 13.561 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b2731c method=bqi.a(IIIIZ)I @ 301
Event: 13.566 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b18104 method=bqi.a(IIIII)I @ 107
Event: 13.588 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b25060 method=bqi.a(IIIIZ)I @ 317
Event: 13.609 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b29b08 method=bqi.a(IIIIZ)I @ 333
Event: 13.641 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b307b0 method=bqi.a(IIIIZ)I @ 179
Event: 13.686 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b328ec method=bqi.a(IIIIZ)I @ 238
Event: 13.717 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Uncommon trap: reason=intrinsic action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002b37b40 method=bqi.a(IIIIZ)I @ 209

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 14.615 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c12d8a78) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.618 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c12e0110) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.643 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c12e4338) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.644 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c12e7ed8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.646 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c12ed670) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.647 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c12f15b8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.648 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c12f7c28) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.655 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c135eb48) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.658 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c13635f0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 14.659 Thread 0x0000000001d60000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c1366710) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]

Events (10 events):
Event: 14.647 loading class bdx
Event: 14.647 loading class bdx done
Event: 14.648 loading class bfz
Event: 14.648 loading class bfz done
Event: 14.655 loading class bcb
Event: 14.655 loading class bcb done
Event: 14.657 loading class bcf
Event: 14.657 loading class bcf done
Event: 14.659 loading class bbo
Event: 14.659 loading class bbo done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f350000 - 0x000000013f384000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
0x00000000771e0000 - 0x0000000077389000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076fc0000 - 0x00000000770df000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd2f0000 - 0x000007fefd35c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007feff410000 - 0x000007feff4eb000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefd9f0000 - 0x000007fefda8f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefe350000 - 0x000007fefe36f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefdbd0000 - 0x000007fefdcfd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00000000770e0000 - 0x00000000771da000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feff200000 - 0x000007feff267000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007feff270000 - 0x000007feff27e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefe3a0000 - 0x000007fefe469000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefbba0000 - 0x000007fefbd94000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefdd90000 - 0x000007fefde01000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefdd00000 - 0x000007fefdd2e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefdf70000 - 0x000007fefe079000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000000005fd40000 - 0x000000005fe12000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000005f4e0000 - 0x000000005fd3a000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefa630000 - 0x000007fefa639000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefd540000 - 0x000007fefd58d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe370000 - 0x000007fefe378000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef9ac0000 - 0x000007fef9afb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x00000000773a0000 - 0x00000000773a7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000067810000 - 0x000000006781f000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000677e0000 - 0x0000000067808000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\java.dll
0x00000000677c0000 - 0x00000000677d6000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefe470000 - 0x000007feff1f9000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefd590000 - 0x000007fefd793000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefcfb0000 - 0x000007fefcfbf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000067820000 - 0x000000006782d000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\management.dll
0x0000000061830000 - 0x000000006184a000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefc780000 - 0x000007fefc7d5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc770000 - 0x000007fefc777000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x0000000061850000 - 0x0000000061861000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\nio.dll
0x000007fefab00000 - 0x000007fefab15000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef2c50000 - 0x000007fef2c65000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef2c30000 - 0x000007fef2c49000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefc600000 - 0x000007fefc65b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef2c20000 - 0x000007fef2c2b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefa810000 - 0x000007fefa837000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefa800000 - 0x000007fefa80b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefa5c0000 - 0x000007fefa613000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000007fef9600000 - 0x000007fef9608000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180051000     C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-139750859930917\lwjgl64.dll
0x000007feeb360000 - 0x000007feeb47d000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x000007feed650000 - 0x000007feed67d000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x000007feeb810000 - 0x000007feeb901000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x000007fef3240000 - 0x000007fef3248000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x000007fefd360000 - 0x000007fefd537000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefd2b0000 - 0x000007fefd2e6000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007fefde90000 - 0x000007fefdf67000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefcfc0000 - 0x000007fefcfda000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fefb3c0000 - 0x000007fefb3d8000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefc090000 - 0x000007fefc09c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007fefc7e0000 - 0x000007fefc7f8000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc4e0000 - 0x000007fefc527000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefd280000 - 0x000007fefd29e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefce40000 - 0x000007fefce4f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefa590000 - 0x000007fefa5a8000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007fefa570000 - 0x000007fefa581000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000000005f340000 - 0x000000005f4d8000     C:\Users\LOMU\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fefb9c0000 - 0x000007fefba16000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007feec7b0000 - 0x000007feec84e000     C:\Program Files\Echobit\Evolve\Drivers\EvolveGameTracker_64.dll
0x000007feeafd0000 - 0x000007feeb199000     C:\Program Files\Echobit\Evolve\Drivers\EvolveOverlayHelper_64.dll
0x000007feee690000 - 0x000007feee6b0000     C:\Program Files\Echobit\Evolve\EvolveEasyHook_64.dll
0x000007feed170000 - 0x000007feed259000     C:\Program Files\Echobit\Evolve\Drivers\EvolveOverlayHelperOGL_64.dll
0x0000000058f00000 - 0x000000005952f000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4icd64.dll
0x0000000059530000 - 0x000000005997d000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4dev64.dll
0x000007feeb770000 - 0x000007feeb80c000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x000007feeb720000 - 0x000007feeb762000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x0000000070a40000 - 0x0000000070adc000     C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-139750859930917\avutil-ttv-51.dll
0x0000000065980000 - 0x00000000659d6000     C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-139750859930917\swresample-ttv-0.dll
0x000000006eb80000 - 0x000000006ec50000     C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-139750859930917\libmp3lame-ttv.dll
0x000007fee8490000 - 0x000007fee9834000     C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-139750859930917\libmfxsw64.dll
0x000000005da70000 - 0x000000005db9b000     C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-139750859930917\twitchsdk.dll
0x000007fefd7a0000 - 0x000007fefd9e8000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x000007fefcfe0000 - 0x000007fefcfe4000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
0x000007fefd1c0000 - 0x000007fefd1c4000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
0x000007fefd1d0000 - 0x000007fefd1d4000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
0x000007fefd160000 - 0x000007fefd163000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
0x00000000773b0000 - 0x00000000773b3000     C:\Windows\system32\normaliz.DLL
0x000007fefe080000 - 0x000007fefe347000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x000007fefd170000 - 0x000007fefd175000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
0x0000000001f10000 - 0x0000000001f74000     C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-139750859930917\OpenAL64.dll
0x000007fefdb30000 - 0x000007fefdbc9000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x000007fefb410000 - 0x000007fefb45b000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x000007fefba20000 - 0x000007fefbb4c000     C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
0x000007feeaf40000 - 0x000007feeafc8000     C:\Windows\system32\dsound.dll
0x000007fefb1e0000 - 0x000007fefb20c000     C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll
0x000007fef0c50000 - 0x000007fef0c9f000     C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x000007feed260000 - 0x000007feed385000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-139750859930917 
java_command: net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username Player --version 1.7.10 --gameDir C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft --assetsDir C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets --assetIndex 1.7.10 --uuid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --accessToken d86588e97f71414299e269df513231a9 --userProperties {} --userType legacy --demo
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.3.5\realms-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\java3d\vecmath\1.3.1\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.10.Final\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\LOMU\AppData\Roamin
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
USERNAME=LOMU
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 3135928k(1026556k free), swap 6270000k(3255544k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_25-b18), built on Oct  7 2014 14:25:37 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sun Apr 12 10:12:23 2015
elapsed time: 14 seconds (0d 0h 0m 14s)
```

Comment: Look, can you at least give us some context? When did this error occur? How have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Well, the more you tell us, the more likely we'll be able to help you. As it is, you're getting downvoted in large part for this lack of information.

Comment: i play minecraft before... and my comp suddenly broke,so i go fix it and updated my comp and i download 1.7.10 it kep crashing

Comment: Reinstall minecraft.

Comment: i Did that already

Comment: This error occurs immediately after you run minecraft?

Comment: after i run minecraft 1.7.10,i wait and then it crash everytime

Comment: i dont know about that...

Comment: @WincsFreds - See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/213699/28182) - The `ig4dev64.dll` error means your graphics card is too old to support the newer versions of   Minecraft. You will need to either play on a version under 1.7.2, or replace your graphics card.

Answer (score -3):

Are you using the new Minecraft launcher Mojang provided?

Try run Minecraft as an administrator first. Access violation means Java requires UAC to continue.

I have been having trouble with the "Runtime" working on my PC. Use the old MC launcher and also downgrade your Java to Java 7 see if it works.

Java 7 - http://www.java.com/en/download/manual_java7.jsp

Old MC Launcher - https://launcher.mojang.com/download/Minecraft.exe

Comment: i will try it but if it fails again ill just figure what to do

Comment: as i expected it didnt work..

Comment: I see what may be causing the problem. In the debug information you put, there is ig4dev64.dll which is an Intel driver for your graphics. Are you using your internal graphics to play or do you have another graphics card?

Comment: intel graphics why?

Comment: It seems like Java is referencing your crash to your Intel graphics driver. Have you tried updating/reinstalling your graphics driver?

Comment: no not yet.Should i update it or not?

Comment: Go ahead, its always best to update :D

Comment: can u tell me how to downgrade java 8 to java 7?

Comment: Go to your Control Panel --> Programs and Features --> Uninstall Java 8