# Minecraft crashes on launch with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, Problematic frame: ig4dev32.dll or ig4dev64.dll or ig4icd32.dll or ig4icd64.dll

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to launch Minecraft 1.7.4 or newer, the game crashes on startup, and the game output screen says this:

```
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=*, pid=*, tid=*
#
# JRE version: Java™ SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot™ Client VM (* mixed mode, sharing windows-* )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4dev32.dll+0x3e88]
OR
# C  [ig4dev64.dll+0x55ec]
OR
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x104a77]
OR 
# C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x84930a]
```

This happens with both Java 7 and 8.

What causes this error, and what can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: This question is meant to serve as a coherent error description for this error (which comes up like once a week), meant for linking questions about this (which are very common) as a duplicate of this one. The current [go-to duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178772/minecraft-forge-1-7-10-keeps-crashing-as-soon-as-i-launch-the-game) is a very poor example of the problem, since while fairly complete, is far from a minimal example.

Comment: This post is subject to a [Arqade Meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com) discussion: [A chain of duplicate Minecraft questions](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12001/a-chain-of-duplicate-minecraft-questions)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Your graphics card does not support newer versions of Minecraft.**

If you have another GPU in your computer, try running Minecraft with that: right mouse button on the executable → Run With → (something other than "integrated"). Dedicated GPUs tend to have better supported/more compatible drivers than integrated ones.

If you do not have another GPU, then there is nothing you can do about this error, short of replacing your (presumably quite old) graphics card, or even your entire computer.

From the support pages on [minecraft.net](http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/references/intel-4-series-chipsets/) regarding this issue:

> ### Intel 4 Series Chipsets
>
> Some chipsets in the Intel 4 Series, most notably the Intel 965
>   Express Chipset are known to have issues with OpenGL support, that may
>   throw an access violation.
>
> All Intel GPUs using the `ig4dev32.dll` and `ig4dev64.dll` drivers are
>   prone to this issue. A full list of affected devices can be found
>   [here](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18223/eng/relnotes_win7_gfx.htm).
>
> #### Solution
>
> This error currently only affects all versions past 1.7.4 - and will
>   likely affect all future versions of Minecraft.
>
> As such, you may work around this error by using a version prior to
>   1.7.4, such as 1.7.2. To play 1.7.4 or later versions, you will need a new computer. Alternatively for desktop users, you can buy a new GPU,
>   but the fact that your computer has an Intel 965 Chipset means that
>   your computer is likely to be very old, and a new computer may be a
>   better way to go.

Answer (score 11):

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x43dc2]
```

`ig4icd32.dll` appears to be part of Intel's graphics drivers.

From [Mojang's bug entry on this, MC-14051](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-14051):

> The Intel 4 Series (and older) video cards are unable to play 1.7.4 and future versions of Minecraft. You will need to buy a new video card or computer to play new versions.
>
> For now, you can still play 1.7.2 or older versions of the game. To change your game to a different version, start the launcher. Select Edit Profile. In the "Use Version" dropdown menu, select the game version you want. Then click Save Profile.

If you have another GPU in your computer, try running Minecraft with that, as per: right mouse button on the executable → Run With → (something other than "integrated").  Dedicated GPUs tend to have better supported/more compatible drivers than integrated ones.

If you do not have another GPU, or for some reason (power requirements) cannot use them, updating your graphics drivers may get it working.  Check out [Mojang's support article](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928493-error-bad-video-card-driver) for information on what to do.

Answer (score 4):

I allocated more RAM by changing the JVM Arguments to this: `-Xmx3G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M` and it fixed the error.