# LWJGL games crash with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: technical-issues

I have this problem in almost all games that use Java/LWJGL, like Minecraft, 3079 -- Block Action RPG, and 3089 -- Futuristic Action RPG.

### Computer specifications

- OS: Windows 8.1 x64
- CPU: Intel i5-3230M Quad Core @ 2.6 GHz (3.2 GHz with Turbo Boost)
- RAM: 8 GB DDR3 @ 1600 MHz
- GPU: Nvidia Optimus with:

  - Intel HD Graphics 4000 (driver version 10.18.10.3958, can't update to newer versions for reasons unknown)
  - Nvidia GeForce GT 740M (1 GB VRAM, driver version 353.30, default GPU for *all* applications)
- Java: JRE 7u80 (also happens with JRE 8u60)

### Example crash log

http://pastebin.com/3FvYqGyf (the original file is 30.5 kB)

### More details

I usually get this problem the second time I launch a LWJGL game, but it can happen the first time.

I can get to those games' launchers, but getting the games themselves to run is almost impossible.

Don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Thanks in advance for your answer(s).

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is related, but I'd start by [pointing my finger at Intel Graphics 4000](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213699/minecraft-crashes-on-launch-with-exception-access-violation-problematic-frame) - Are you sure that the applications are running with your Nvidia card? A lot of laptops disable the dedicated graphics when on battery, even when they're set to default

Comment: @Robotnik: my laptop is almost never on battery, and I set Optimus to only use the GT 740M in the Nvidia Control Panel. EDIT: unlike the question you linked, the problematic frame is `# C  0x000000000bfdddad`, not a DLL name+offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the x86 version of Java fixed my problem.

[Robotnik's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237429/lwjgl-games-crash-with-exception-access-violation#comment324511_237429) was rather close to the problem. The x64 version of Java does not play well with Intel Graphics drivers, it seems.