# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in vanilla Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I already have asked this question and have it marked as off-topic but I thought that new info made this on topic again.

([Minecraft crashes with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362635/minecraft-crashes-with-exception-access-violation))

I had the question closed because modded support isn't done here. So today I made a new minecraft instance with just forge to check mods one by one to see if a particular mod is the problem, and the instance crashed the same way.

Upon further investigation, it seems like there's a chance of experiencing this kind of crash while entering world ONLY. I made a completely vanilla (no forge) instance and it's happened too. It's since happened 3-4 times in about 20 attempts.

So while mods seem to exacerbate the problem (Vanilla w/ or w/o forge hasn't crashed during loading, and the forge version seem to crash more often from my limited testing) there seems to be an underlying issue at work.

Here's the log of vanilla w/ forge:

```
[15:28:30] [Client thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureMap]: Created: 512x512 textures-atlas
[15:28:32] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Applying holder lookups
[15:28:32] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Holder lookups applied
[15:28:32] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Injecting itemstacks
[15:28:32] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Itemstack injection complete
[15:28:32] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader has successfully loaded 4 mods
[15:28:32] [Client thread/WARN] [minecraft/GameSettings]: Skipping bad option: lastServer:
[15:28:32] [Client thread/INFO] [mojang/NarratorWindows]: Narrator library for x64 successfully loaded
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000541ed4be, pid=1224, tid=0x0000000000001d48
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_231-b11) (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.231-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x10d4be]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

With the full log: https://pastebin.com/J6Xt636v

And here's the log for vanilla w/o forge:

```
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at ayj.a(SourceFile:263)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at ayj$a.close(SourceFile:244)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at aye.b(SourceFile:160)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at aye.a(SourceFile:145)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at bgx.c(SourceFile:37)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at bgx.run(SourceFile:30)
[15:33:53] [File IO Thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005437005b, pid=4424, tid=0x0000000000003ccc
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_231-b11) (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.231-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x29005b]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

And the full log: https://pastebin.com/2ApcGGxT

More info can be found in the question linked at the start.

**EDIT:**

Pasting info from the other question

I've tried to look around but almost all information for this type of crash relates to intel integrated graphics (and this is not the case). Pretty much the only good info I've found is here: Minecraft EXCEPTION ACCESS VIOLATION

But it does not have a solution.

I have already reinstalled both Minecraft and Java, and I've updated all drivers. I have run MemTest86 like it says there for a full pass without errors, and I've run LinX like it says and it stopped for an error after a couple of runs, but I don't know what that means.

The RAM appears to otherwise work fine.

### PC specs

- Intel i5 750 quad core 2.67 GHz
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 950
- Intel SSD 256 G
- HDD 1T (shouldn't mattter, nothing relevant is installed here)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft) See the second answer - the first item listed discusses this error.

Comment: The problematic frame is a jvm, so a problem in the virtual machine. I have the last version of java 8, so that's not the problem. I have run a memory test but it's returned no error, and the memory seems to otherwise work fine for everything else.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a JVM crash, not even just a Minecraft crash. That's much rarer. BTW, your real first name is in the log. If that matters to you, you should make a new Pastebin, replace the link here and then tell me so that I can figure out how the old version can get removed.

Comment: I don't care enough to replace all instances in the logs

Comment: Hey @Bibliotebarbarian - the standard procedure here would be to edit your previous post to make it on-topic, and we could then reopen it.

Comment: @schism sorry, didn't know that. Should I do that or keep this since I've already done it?

Comment: No worries! You could paste the entire contents of this post in place of your old post; this will automatically place it into the a review queue to reopen it.

Comment: Should I delete this question then?