# Minecraft Java crashes randomly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My minecraft game has been crashing alot lately, and i dont kow why. It also happens with other games and i frequently get blue screen errors. I believe it is a hardware problem but does [this crash log support that idea?](https://justpaste.it/6zfxu) The error i usually get it "exception_access_violation" but i sometimes get "exception_illegal_instructuion"

A few things:

1. My system can run minecraft, i used to be able to play Minecraft with no issues at an amazing frame rate (usually 90 to 160)
2. I have updated my Intel Graphics drivers to the latest one and even tested the previous version
3. I have the latest version of the Minecraft launcher
4. I have the latest version of Java installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft Vanilla 1.9 crash with problematic frame ig8icd64.dll](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257708/minecraft-vanilla-1-9-crash-with-problematic-frame-ig8icd64-dll)

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a bug with Minecraft, but if you are running into this problem with other games, probably not. I’m going to suggest turning it off and turning it back on, though you’ve probably already tried that. ;) My only other suggestions are to 1. Make sure you don’t have anything weird or harmful on your computer, 2. Check and see if something got downloaded or is running that could cause a problem like this, and 3. Reach out to a computer technician or someone who’s just good with computers.